# Python - copy content of a file to another one except the the two first and last lines

Tags: python, file, split

I need to copy the content of a file to another one except the first two and  the last two lines of that file.

For that purpose I wrote this function

```
    def copy_file(self, input_file, output_file):
        line_nr = 1
        fout = open(output_file, "w+")
        with open(input_file, 'r') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                if line_nr == 1 or line_nr == 2 or line_nr == 53 and line_nr == 54 :
                    continue
                new_line = line.split(' ', 1)[-1]
                fout.write(new_line)

        fp.close()
```

I was able to achieve what I desired by hardcoding the line numbers that I wanted to ignore but I would like to make this function more generic.

How can I do it?

I want to achieve something like this

### Original file

```
line to be ignored
line to be ignored
Timestamp message
Timestamp message
line to be ignored
line to be ignored
```

### Expected output

```
message
message
```

Comment: Unless the file is a problematic size for reading into memory, you can use readlines() to get a list of all lines and then simply write `lines[2:-2]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is going through the file manually, line by line, which as you can see can be impractical and tedious. A good alternative is to use list splicing and the function `f.read.splitlines(True)`

Try this:

```py
def copy_file(input_file, output_file):
    line_nr = 1
    fout = open(output_file, "w+")
    with open(input_file, 'r') as fp:
        text = fp.read().splitlines(True)[2:-2]
        fout.writelines(text)

    fp.close()
```

The beginning of the code is the same as yours. However, instead of looping through the file, line by line, I use the code `fp.read().splitlines(True)`. This returns the entire file in a list, where each element is a line. From their, I can use list splicing `[2:-2]` to get rid of the first 2 and last 2 elements of the list. Finally, I can then write these to the new file with `fout.writelines(text)`, which turns a list into text to write into a file.

Comment: `list(f)` avoids creating a massive string just to replace it with a lot of smaller ones.

Comment: what if I want to do something with the lines like for example only copying the content that comes after the first comma ?

Comment: @DavisHerring what do you mean?

Comment: @FábioPires can you give me an example input and output

Comment: @ThePilotDude edited my question with an example

Comment: @FábioPires my code achieves that. Can you add in the example the whole after the first comma thing

Comment: @ThePilotDude: `f.read()` creates a string with the whole contents of the file.  Why do that just to cut it up when you could make just the lines directly?

Comment: @DavisHerring because it works and I understand it

Comment: You should use `list(f)` not `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it does the same thing, and you're welcome to use `list(f)` in your own code, but im going to stick to this

Comment: well, no it doesn't do the same thing. `f.read().splitlines()` unnecessarily requires the whole string in memory along with the list of lines at the same time. Which is why it is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do this efficiently, keeping at most "skip_last" elements in memory. This uses `itertools.islice` to slice the file iterator, and a `collections.deque` to efficiently keep a buffer of lines:

```
import itertools
import collections

def copy_file(
    input_file: str,
    output_file: str,
    skip_first: int,
    skip_last: int
) -> None:
    with open(input_file) as fin, open(output_file, 'w') as fout:
        skipped_beginning = itertools.islice(fin, skip_first, None)
        buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=skip_last)
        buffer.extend(itertools.islice(skipped_beginning, skip_last))
        for line in skipped_beginning:
            fout.write(buffer.popleft())
            buffer.append(line)
```